# Appending PFObject to Array - EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, exc-bad-access

I am currently using Swift and Parse and have run into an issue which I haven't been able resolve for the past several hours.

On a button click, I am attempting to add an Employee object to an Event object's eventAttendee's array.

```
@IBAction func joinEvent(sender: AnyObject) {
    var employee = Employee.currentUser()
    employee.events.append(event)
    employee.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)

    event.eventAttendees.append(employee)
    event.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)
}
```

The event is added to the employee events, but the employee is not added to the event attendees list. The function throws a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) on the append(employee) line, with no other error message.

My event class looks like this:

```
class VolunteerEvent : PFObject, PFSubclassing {

@NSManaged var eventName: String
@NSManaged var dateOfEvent: NSDate
@NSManaged var eventDescription: String
@NSManaged var eventURL: String?
@NSManaged var eventImage: PFFile

@NSManaged var contactEmail: String
@NSManaged var contactPhone: NSNumber

@NSManaged var eventOrganizer: Employee
@NSManaged var eventAttendees: [Employee]

class func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "VolunteerEvent"
}
}
```

My Employee class extends PFUser, although when I print out the description of my employee I get that it is a PFUser. I can't tell if this is the issue. When I print out the event, it looks like I expect it to look. I also tried switching the eventAttendees to be an array of PFUser's instead of Employee's, but that didn't work either.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is the events property a valid, initialised array instance?

Comment: Although I never explicitly initialize it, it seems like Parse does that because when it is printed I get back `[]`. I thought that might be the issue but I figure if I can print it, it must be initialized right?

Comment: The other question would be is `event` valid when your code runs? since it appears to defined outside this function.

Comment: It's defined within the class and is set before I call the view controller. I use all the other attributes of `event` in functions before I call this function so it must be a valid `VolunteerEvent`. EXC_BAD_ACCESS definitely sounds like a memory access issue, but it seems like I can access both `event.eventAttendees` and `employee`, so I'm beginning to think it has something to do with my Parse setup.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in this method and examine `employee.events` via 'po employee.events' in the debug console

Comment: Thanks for the help and I'm glad I learned about `po`.  It looks like my list wasn't being initialized even though I could access it and print it as an empty list. It looks like I have to change how I'm subclassing, even though the Parse documentation seems to agree with how I did things. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I subclass my PFObjects this way,

```
class Person : PFObject, PFSubclassing {

    var firstName: String {
        get {
            return objectForKey("firstName") as? String ?? ""
        }
        set {
            setObject(newValue, forKey: "firstName")
        }
     }
}
```

This way if there is no string in the parse database, I don't get nil, i get an empty string.

**You can do this with your array, in fact all your object properties.**

If nothing is returned, then you will get an empty array of Employee, rather than a nil object - which will cause your crash when you try an append to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your array before adding to it. Try `var eventAttendees: [Employee] = []`